# Spring MVC Encoding Issue

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring MVC with Thymeleaf. When I post a form that has ® in it as a parameter, it displays it in windows-1252 format instead of utf-8.

Here is the input that I post with the form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" id="brand1" value="Brand®">
```

Here is how it looks in the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/categories?brand=Brand%AE&x=87&y=37
```

I've done some research and looks like ® is equal to %AE in windows-1252, but is equal to %C2%AE in utf-8. When I manually post the URL with %C2%AE, it interprets it correctly.

I'm using IntelliJ 14.1.3 on Windows 7, and my web server is Tomcat 8.0.21.
Starting Tomcat 8.0.3-RC, default URI Encoding is set to utf-8 in Tomcat, and I also verified that my IDE and Project Encodings are set to utf-8 in IntelliJ. Also, my HTML file has `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` tag at the beginning.

Do you have any idea how can I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe spring comes shipped with a character encoding filter that will set the encoding on the HttpServletRequest object. Have you tried looking into that?

Comment: Yeah, I have the following in my config `@Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource getMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        resource.setBasename("classpath:i18n/messages");
        resource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resource;
    }` I'm guessing this overrides the default.